# iteration for with if and continue

Tags: java, iterator

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    int b = 0, i;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        if (i % 5 <= 2) {
            continue;
        }
        b += ++i;
    }
    System.out.print(b);
```

why the result output is 13? not 28?

- iteration 0, b = 0 (5%0 = 0, continue;)
- iteration 1, b = 0 (5%1 = 1, continue;)
- iteration 2, b = 0 (5%2 = 2, continue;)
- iteration 3, b = 4 (5%3 = 3, b += ++i;)
- iteration 4, b = 9 (5%4 = 4, b += ++i;)
- iteration 5, b = 9 (5%5 = 0, continue;)
- iteration 6, b = 9 (5%6 = 1, continue;)
- iteration 7, b = 9 (5%7 = 2, continue;)
- iteration 8, b = 18 (5%8 = 3, b += ++i;)
- iteration 9, b = 28 (5%9 = 4, b += ++i;)

Comment: You are incrementing `i` twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loop iterations where `i` starts out `4` or `9` do not occur, because `++i` adds to `i` in the line `b += ++i;`.  But that doesn't stop the `for` loop increment operation `i++` from occurring also.  This is the true iteration sequence:

- iteration 0, i = 0, b = 0 (0%5 = 0, continue;)
- iteration 1, i = 1, b = 0 (1%5 = 1, continue;)
- iteration 2, i = 2, b = 0 (2%5 = 2, continue;)
- iteration 3, i = 3, b = 4 (3%5 = 3, b += ++i;, i is now 4)
- iteration 4, i = 5, b = 4 (5%5 = 0, continue;)
- iteration 5, i = 6, b = 4 (6%5 = 1, continue;)
- iteration 6, i = 7, b = 4 (7%5 = 2, continue;)
- iteration 7, i = 8, b = 13 (8%5 = 3, b += ++i;, i is now 9)

Comment: Oh I see, so the value of i is also changed by increment. Thanks!

Comment: ```5%n``` must be ```n%5```.

Comment: @saka1029 I didn't even notice that the order was wrong in the question!  I've corrected it in my answer.